# When does Decorator code execute?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

For the below given syntax,

```
import validator from "./ZipCodeValidator";
```

that imports dictionary of objects from `ZipCodeValidator.ts` to name `validator` in current name space,  at build/bundling time,

where `ZipCodeValidator.ts` looks like:

```
export class C {
    @f()
    @g()
    method() {}
}
```

Are decorators(`f` & `g`) annotated to methods in `ZipCodeValidator.ts` executed on running import statement(above) at build/bundling time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decorators are always executed when the class declaration is executed. Since most class declarations are often in the top-level scope of a module, that *can* mean that they run when the code is executed, but there's nothing stopping you from having a class declaration inside of another function, in which case the decorators would only run when that function was called.

In your specific case, the decorator factory `f()` would run during the declaration to return the actual decorator function, and then the class declaration will call the decorator.

The decorator function itself could always mutate the `method` to call some custom logic when `method` is called, but the decorator itself is long done by then.

Comment: In python, decorators are executed at import time

Comment: Are you sure about that? What if the class is declared inside of a function?

Comment: Whether it is class declaration or function declaration, When does decorator execute?

Comment: I feel like I've already answered that. When the declaration is executed, the decorators run.

Comment: When does declaration execute?

Comment: Like any other JavaScript code, execution starts at the top of the file and works its way down. Once execution reaches the class declaration, the decorators will run.

Comment: Also as mentioned, it is not the import that triggers execution of decorators, it is just that importing a file usually executes the code in the file, which also means the decorators execute. You can see the same in python with an example like this: https://repl.it/@loganfsmyth/MoralMediumorchidRuntimeenvironment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170404/discussion-between-loganfsmyth-and-overexchange).